# PHP: Replace values in mySQL result array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to replace parts of the below result set in the $data array, e.g. I want to format price with a thousand separator and to add a variable hyperlink instead of details.

The query itself works and I know how to modify the values as needed but I don't know how to replace the values in the array or better only pass the modifed values to the array.

**Note:** I need to do this in PHP (not in mySQL directly).

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemId, price, details FROM offers WHERE itemId LIKE 'DE%' ORDER BY itemId");
$stmt->execute();
$resultX = $stmt->get_result(); 
$rowCountX = $resultX->num_rows;
$data = array();

while($rows = $resultX->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $rows; // array that I want to change
}
```

**Update:**

**Example:**
**itemId:** b500 -> should be b500 // unchanged
**Price:** 1500 -> should be 1,500
**Details:** Item 123 -> [Item 123](http://%3Ca%20href=%22page.php%22%3EItem%20123%3C/a%3E)

Can someone help me with this ?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: can you add sample input and output.

Comment: @aviboy2006: Thanks. It's a general question but I provided some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if i understand the issue, but if you want to change the values before "display", or return a to view, on your code just do something like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT itemId, price, details FROM offers WHERE itemId LIKE 'DE%' ORDER BY itemId");
$stmt->execute();
$resultX = $stmt->get_result(); 
$rowCountX = $resultX->num_rows;
$data = array();
$rows = $resultX->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $row['price'] =  number_format( $row['price'] , 2 , "" , "," );
    $row['details'] = '<a href="#linkhere">'.$row['details'].'</a>';
    $data[] = $row; // array that I want to change
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this :
$data = array();

```
while($rows = $resultX->fetch_assoc()) {
    $input_data = array();
    $input_data['price']= formatIndian($rows['price']);
    $input_data['details']= "<a href='' > ". $row['details']."</a>";
    $data[]= $input_data;
}
```

**Note** : `formatIndian` its just any function which covert number to Indian format